# How to run windows executable and delete files from sub folders

Tags: vbscript, scripting

I need a quick script do two parts.

1. Run a windows executable
2. Delete files within a folder and subfolders (*.jpg, *.img).

The first part of the below script works (running the executable) but I am getting stuck on part 2.  I get

> Cannot use parentheses when calling a sub

The error is on the line with the `RecursiveDelete` call.  I actually cut and pasted that code from another SO question.  I have googled the error but still don't understand.

Can anybody know how to get this script working?

```
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.Run chr(34) & "C:\Users\acer\Desktop\CT\process.exe" & Chr(34), 0
Set WshShell = Nothing

Dim PicArray(2)
Dim p

PicArray(1) = "*.jpg"
PicArray(2) = "*.img"

For p = 1 To 2
  RecursiveDelete ("D:\pictures", PicArray(p))
Next p

Private Sub RecursiveDelete(ByVal Path As String, ByVal Filter As String)
  Dim s
  For Each s In System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories(Path)
    try
      RecursiveDelete(s, Filter)
    catch dirEx as exception
      debug.writeline("Cannot Access " & s & " : " & dirEx.message
    end try
  Next

  For Each s In System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(Path, Filter)
    try
      System.IO.File.Delete(s)
    catch ex as exception
      debug.writeline("Cannot delete " & s & " : " & ex.message)
    end try
  Next
End Sub
```

Update: Revised answer from Hackoo that works great.

```
Option Explicit
Dim fso,RootFolder, wshShell
set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
RootFolder = "D:\pictures"
Set RootFolder = fso.GetFolder(RootFolder)
Call RecursiveDelete(RootFolder)

Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.Run chr(34) & "C:\process.exe" & Chr(34), 0
Set WshShell = Nothing

'*****************************************************************************
Function RecursiveDelete(Folder)
    Dim File,MyFile,Ext,i,SubFolder
    Set Folder = fso.GetFolder(Folder)
    For each File in Folder.Files
    Set MyFile = fso.GetFile(File)
        Ext = Array("iMG","JPG")
        For i = LBound(Ext) To UBound(Ext)
            If LCase(fso.GetExtensionName(File.name)) = LCase(Ext(i)) Then 
                MyFile.Delete()
                Exit For
            end if
        Next
    Next
    For each SubFolder in Folder.SubFolders
        Call RecursiveDelete(SubFolder)
    Next
End Function
'*****************************************************************************
```

Comment: It is not vbscript. Looks like VB.NET

Comment: The function RecursiveDelete is written in VB.NET and you must translate it in vbscript ;)

Comment: I sort of Read some hints about that. I wouldn't know how to do it. Do you?.:)

Comment: Your question is tagged `vbscript`, but your code looks like `vb6`. Decide on one. Also, if you really have googled the error message you must have come across Eric Lippert's blog post [*What do you mean "cannot use parentheses?"*](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2003/09/15/52996.aspx), which explains the problem in every gory detail.

Comment: When I asked the question I had no idea what I was doing let alone I was dealing with two different languages.  That influenced the poor question. @hackoo was able to read in between the lines and answer :)

Comment: I modified my question and added the compete answer for clarity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this way :

```
Option Explicit
Dim fso,RootFolder
set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
RootFolder = "D:\pictures"
Set RootFolder = fso.GetFolder(RootFolder)
Call RecursiveDelete(RootFolder)
Msgbox "Pictures Cleaned !",vbInformation,"Pictures Cleaned !"
'*****************************************************************************
Function RecursiveDelete(Folder)
    Dim File,MyFile,Ext,i,SubFolder
    Set Folder = fso.GetFolder(Folder)
    For each File in Folder.Files
    Set MyFile = fso.GetFile(File)
        Ext = Array("jpg","img")
        For i = LBound(Ext) To UBound(Ext)
            If LCase(fso.GetExtensionName(File.name)) = LCase(Ext(i)) Then 
                MyFile.Delete()
                Exit For
            end if
        Next
    Next
    For each SubFolder in Folder.SubFolders
        Call RecursiveDelete(SubFolder)
    Next
End Function
'*****************************************************************************
```

Comment: Awesome answer.  works perfectly.  I added the complete code with both steps 1 & 2 in my question. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing the array item into RecursiveDelete, obtain the contents of the array item into a variable within the loop, and pass that variable instead.

Code would be similar to this-  did not have a chance to test syntax.

```
 For p = 1 To 2
      Dim PicItem 
      PicItem = PicArray(p)
    RecursiveDelete ("D:\pictures", PicItem )
 Next p
```

Comment: I tried that before I posted here. It didn't work. It must be related to vb.net as mentioned above.